# How are funds stored inside a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Can you guys please help me to understand how does a contract temporarily keeps a funds inside itself? I am looking the Solidity docs and tutorials and I see, that it is possible to keep a funds inside a contract for some time and then to send these funds to owner using the `suicide()` method.

I refer to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/a-101-noob-intro-to-programming-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-695d15c1dab4). According to the code example, [the contract](https://github.com/eshon/conference/blob/master/contracts/Conference.sol) looks like this:

```
contract Conference { 

   address public organizer;
   mapping (address => uint) public registrantsPaid;
   uint public numRegistrants;

   // ...

   function buyTicket() public returns (bool success) { 
     if (numRegistrants >= quota) { 
         return false; 
     }
     else {
         registrantsPaid[msg.sender] = msg.value;
         numRegistrants++;
         return true;
     }
   }

   // ...

  function destroy() { // so funds not locked in contract forever
     if (msg.sender == organizer) {
        suicide(organizer); // send funds to organizer
     }
  }
}
```

As far as I understand from this example, the function `buyTicket()` should take some funds from a user calling this transaction and persist it somehow inside a blockchain as a stored data. But I don't see any payments here, I can only see that we put user's value and address inside the internal mapping, such as `registrantsPaid[msg.sender] = msg.value;`.

Can you please explain to me, what exactly happens in the function `buyTicket()`? How does the `suicide(organizer)` knows where all funds are stored inside a contract? Is there actual money are transferred form user to a contract inside the `buyTicket()` function? Where exactly the `destroy()` is calling?

Thank you very much. Sorry, for noobish question :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `buyTicket`, your funds are saved to the contract. `registrantsPaid` only records funds for every account that has called `buyTicket`. All funds are saved to the contract, because a contract is an account.

If you call the `destroy` function, the funds of the contract will be refunded to `organizer` account. You can get the balance of the contract by `this.balance`.

Your code has a bug , if `numRegistrants >= quota` is true, the user calling `buyTicket` will lose some funds, so you must refund him. Modified as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Conference { 

   address public organizer;
   mapping (address => uint) public registrantsPaid;
   uint public numRegistrants;
    uint quota = 2000;
   // ...

   function buyTicket() payable public returns (bool success) { 
        require(numRegistrants >= quota);
        registrantsPaid[msg.sender] = msg.value;
         numRegistrants++;
         return true;
   }

   // ...

  function destroy() { // so funds not locked in contract forever
     if (msg.sender == organizer) {
        suicide(organizer); // send funds to organizer
     }
  }

  function getContractBalance() constant returns (uint){
    return this.balance;    
  }

}
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: So, the rule is: when a customer calls a public function marked as `payable`, then the sum of money equals to `msg.value` are moved from his wallet to the contract wallet automatically? Am I right? Sorry, this piese of code is a bit confusing for me, because it is implicit.

Comment: And thank you for the code correction! I appreciate that!

Comment: Yes, this money will be stored to contract~